# Sencha Touch 2 : Is it possible to achieve inheritance for view objects?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need some suggestions on the following aspect.

**BackGround:**

I am working on Sencha 2 MVC Application. 
In my application, I have a toolbar on several screens.
Currently, I have created a class for the toolbar and then adding the toolbar using xType on the required views as xType: 'customizedToolbar'. 
But instead of that,I want to declare a parent class where this toolbar is defined and then extend this parent class from all other child classes so I can avoid adding the toolbar everytime using xType.

For an example, below is the sample application,

Ext.application({
            app:'testmixin',
            autoCreateViewport: true,

```
        launch: function()    {

// Parent Class
        Ext.define('MyParentClass', {
            extend: Ext.Panel,
                mixinConfig: {
                        id: 'myMixinIdentifier'
                         },
                config: {
                // Is there a way that the items defined in this class will be added in the child class         
                items:[

                    {
                        xtype : 'emailfield',
                        name : 'name',
                        id : 'userName',
                        placeHolder : 'Email',

                    },

                    ]

                    },


                });


                // Main Class
    Ext.define('MyMainClass', {
    // Benefit of using mixins is that you can add to your class with one
    // or more mixins, rather than by extending another class
            extend: Ext.Panel,
            mixins: {
                myMixinIdentifier: 'MyParentClass'
            },

        constructor: function(config) {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            this.sample();
            },
        });


    var panel = Ext.create('MyMainClass');
            panel.test('abc');
            panel.test1('abc');
            Ext.Viewport.add(panel);


}

    });
```

Is is possible to add an item in the Parent class and it will be added automatically in the child class thru inheritance?

Thanks
  Gendaful

Comment: I am also currently using what you've used above, and have been looking for the same kind of functionality. Any solutions found yet ?

Comment: Hi @SashaZd : No solution found so far. Waiting for some inputs from other guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does not use mixing but basic class inheritance :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true
});

Ext.application({
    name : ('SF' || 'SenchaFiddle'),

    launch : function() {

        Ext.define('PanelWithToolbar', {
            extend: 'Ext.Container',
            xtype: 'panelwithtoolbar',

            config: {
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'top'
                }]
            }
        });

        Ext.define('PanelA', {
            extend: 'PanelWithToolbar',
            xtype: 'panela'
        });

        Ext.define('PanelB', {
            extend: 'PanelWithToolbar',
            xtype: 'panelb'
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent: true
            },

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panela',
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    html: 'Home Screen'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panelb',
                    title: 'Contact',
                    iconCls: 'user',
                    html: 'Contact Screen'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/OheKw/)

Comment: Thanks Man. I learnt one thing that using mixins, we can not reuse the view objects the same way we do for methods but using Extends we can do!.